# Max traffic - 1Mbps up

Tags: web-server, traffic

I was wondering how to calculate the maximum traffic/load that I could potentially serve having a 1Mbps up? I know that it depends also on external factors but roughly what would be the max output. Mainly web server: dynamic content (thumbnails, text etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your theoretical maximum throughput at 1Mb/s would be

- 60 Mb/min, or 7.5 MB/min; (remember 8 bits in a byte)
- 3600 Mb/hour, or 450 MB/hour

Note that this is highly theoretical and does not include things like

- ethernet, IP, or TCP headers and checksums;
- non-data carrying packets such as SYN, ACK, various ICMP packets
- any allowance for non-duplexed data (ie if you have 1Mb/s total, then every request IN means you can't be sending OUT that instant)
- any allowance for local compute calculations that take longer to do than to transmit (ie generating a custom image, DB lookups, whatever)

So in this highly oversimplified case, if you figure peak demand for this web server is less than those values, you are good to go.

Comment: Not to mention that NIC drivers are not 100% efficient, so they will also slow you down.

Comment: True, but I would hope even an inefficient driver was capable of keeping a 1 Mb/s link saturated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/tools/Data_transfer_speed_calculations